# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping in HalfSizePresentationController class

Tags: swift

I tried to implement presenting modal view controller on the other viewcontroller sized to half parent view controller.

[Present modal view controller in half size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288017/present-modal-view-controller-in-half-size)

when i run this error is show :

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

the code problem ?

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
    return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presentingViewController!)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in cases where you get `unexpectedly found nil...` the culprit is something you try to force unwrap with !

In your case the only thing with a ! is `presentingViewController` so that could be a good place to start looking.

```
if let presenting = presenting {
    return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting!)
}
```

And actually, as I start to look closer at your code, look at your signature:

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?
```

You have a `presentingViewController` external parameter name, but the internal parameter name is `presenting`, and yet you try to use the `presentingViewController` instead of `presenting` when you use your parameters:

```
return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presentingViewController!)
```

Should be:

```
return HalfSizePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting!)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I learned something new as well, don't use the external parameter name if an internal exists. Glad it worked :-)

Comment: something else if i want to dismiss it ,, how should i start ?

Comment: The question you originally referred to has an answer to that. You need to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(_, completion:)` on some `UIViewController` to do that. You can read more about it here.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Comment: self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);

yes it's work :$

thanks